# Which aws instance type is optimal to improve spark shuffle performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark

For my spark application I'm trying to determine whether I should be using 10 r3.8xlarge or 40 r3.2xlarge. I'm mostly concerned with shuffle performance of the application.

If I go with r3.8xlarge I will need to configure 4 worker instances per machine to keep the JVM size down. The worker instances will likely contend with each other for network and disk I/O if they are on the same machine. If I go with 40 r3.2xlarge I will be able to allocate a single worker instance per box, allowing each worker instance to have its own dedicated network and disk I/O.

Since shuffle performance is heavily impacted by disk and network throughput, it seems like going with 40 r3.2xlarge would be the better configuration between the two. Is my analysis correct? Are there other tradeoffs that I'm not taking into account? Does spark bypass the network transfer and read straight from local disk if worker instances are on the same machine?

Comment: This question isn't related to programming. You will probably get better responses on Server Fault...

Comment: I assume this question will get closed for not being programming related, but the r3.8xlarge nodes are generally a very good fit with Spark, disk I/O and network throughput are both much higher in the 8xlarge instances over the 2xlarge instances. Personally I'm looking forward to the 1TB instances coming soon.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have the answer already : `it seems like going with 40 r3.2xlarge would be the better configuration between the two.`

Recommend you go through aws well architect.

**General Design Principles**
The Well-Architected Framework identifies a set of general design principles to
facilitate good design in the cloud:

- **Stop guessing your capacity needs:** Eliminate guessing your
  infrastructure capacity needs. When you make a capacity decision before
  you deploy a system, you might end up sitting on expensive idle resources
  or dealing with the performance implications of limited capacity. With
  cloud computing, these problems can go away. You can use as much or as
  little capacity as you need, and scale up and down automatically.
- **Test systems at production scale:** In a traditional, non-cloud
  environment, it is usually cost-prohibitive to create a duplicate
  environment solely for testing. Consequently, most test environments are
  not tested at live levels of production demand. In the cloud, you can create
  a duplicate environment on demand, complete your testing, and then
  decommission the resources. Because you only pay for the test
  environment when it is running, you can simulate your live environment
  for a fraction of the cost of testing on premises.

refer:

[AWS Well-Architected Framework](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/architecture/AWS_Well-Architected_Framework.pdf)